# fedora 21 javafx not creating mediaplayer

Tags: java, javafx, libav, fedora-21

I recently upgraded to fedora 21. I really like it, however, javafx MediaPlayer doesn't work.

As per the JavaFX System Requirements Site, for a Linux distro to create A MediaPlayer I need:

```
libavcodec53
libavformat53
```

I couldn't find any of these packages in the Fedora repositories (or anything about them with a google search for fedora 21 and I also checked a search for fedora 20, however I managed to get them installed from ATRpm's onto my system successfully and still no luck.

I also installed `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-devel` and `ffmpeg-libs`, and also transcode, and it still throws this exception.

Here Is My StackTrace If You Need It:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/791452441.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not  create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
at brainwaveentrainment.Main.start(Main.java:22)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$55/632695357.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/744796612.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$53/731343915.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$52/7923443.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$45(GtkApplication.java:126)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$43/896313952.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:222)
at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:104)
at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
... 16 more
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction to find the necessary libraries for my fedora system to allow JavaFX to successfully create MediaPlayer objects?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

note that few proprietary components (including JavaFX, Deployment, Java DB and Java Mission Control) are not included in Fedora packages.